# Dialog not shown in canActivate guard

Tags: angular, primeng, angular11

Trying to show a dialog with primeng, but the popup never displays.  There are no errors in the console either...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { ConfirmationService } from 'primeng/api';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TestGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) { }
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {    
    const promise = new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {      
      this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Are you sure you want to continue?',
        accept: () => {
          resolve(true);
        },
        reject: () =>{
          reject(false);
        }
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Adding `<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle"></p-confirmDialog>` in your app component

and make sure you have imported ConfirmDialogModule and provided ConfirmationService